# Loading Google Account Sign-In in an Iframe (Chrome Extension)

Tags: javascript, iframe, google-chrome-extension, google-oauth, google-signin

**The Problem**
I have a chrome extension that loads in an iframe. The extension first loads a Google Login page. The page fails with the following error:

> OAuth2:1 Refused to display
>   'https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth?...' in a frame because it
>   set 'X-Frame-Options' to 'sameorigin'.

I realize that this is a limitation that google sets forth for security reason but in order to provide the user with a more seamless experience, is it possible to overcome it?

For reference, I am using passport with Google OAuth2 strategy:
`const GoogleStrategy = require('passport-google-oauth2').Strategy;`

**Another possibility**
One possibility of avoiding it that comes to mind would be to load the Google Login page in a new tab using `target=_blank"` but then, once the user logs in I'd like the tab to close and the iframe to to authorize the user into the app.

Option #1 is certainly preferable but I'm open for option #2. Any suggestions would certainly help

Answer (score 1):

The simplest that comes to mind is stripping out the incoming `X-Frame-Options` header by using [webRequest](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/webRequest): remove it during the `onHeadersReceived` step. Just keep in mind that usually it is done for good and do it only for your requests.